# NiFi: WAF blocking requests with argument values longer than 400 chars

Tags: apache-nifi

I am running NiFi behind a web application firewall. The firewall complains that the length of the argument values of a request can't be greater than N.

My question is when a user interacts with the NiFi UI, what's making these argument values so long in the HTTP requests.

I am running Apache NiFi 1.10.0

Comment: press F12 in browser and check for non-ok responses

Comment: @daggett,  since the UI is being used by several users inspecting requests originating from my browser may not be sufficient. In NiFi, do you know which arguments could become unbounded in their length ?